# what would a network looks like if the modularity is almost -1?

Tags: networks, social-network

I know that larger positive modularity is good, and often lies between -0.5 and 1. But what would the network looks like if the modularity is appoaching -1? For example, equals to -0.7?

Comment: Modularity is not a function of the network alone. It’s a function of the network’s partition into communities. It’s not possible to reason about modularity except with reference to some set of communities.